# Automatically reject a comment if website field contains anything

Tags: customization, comments, spam

I've done a bunch of searching but can't seem to find a hack to do this, all I can find is how to remove the website field from the form. I want to leave it there, but if someone enters a url into the website field and tries to post a comment, it will automatically be rejected.

Comment: Are you using that field for another purpose? It seems to be silly to show that field, but not allow any entry in that field. If you don't want people to fill out the field, don't show it .. remove it from the form. If you need an additional field on the comment form, there are ways to do that. Me = confused.

Comment: Then spam comments will still come through even if I remove the url field.

Comment: Then why keep the URL box at all? Remove it, and then you'll know that if the website field contains something it isn't because a user accidentally filled it

Comment: My comments are being filled with spam even with Akismet. If I simply remove the url field the spam comments are still going to get through with or without a url. I just need a script that only allows comments through that don't have a url entered, that will solve my spam problem once and for all.

Comment: Spam problems will not go away if you ban URLs from comments. I know a lot about preventing spam in contact forms and comments; wrote a plugin and standalone code to prevent form spam (see https://FormSpammerTrap.com ). My techniques are mostly successful, but still get some spam. Got a new version in the works that will reduce automated spam even more. 
You might think about enabling reCAPTCHA on your comment forms. That helps reduce spam, but nothing that I've found (and I've looked for many years) will completely remove spam.

Comment: @RickHellewell: Modern spammers don't care about comment forms at all. They post comment's data directly, bypassing form's processing, with its validation, captchas, etc. Read my answer for details

Comment: Yes, that is true. Which is why my plugin disallows that direct access, along with other techniques to sense for automated bots. It also allows customizing the comment form.  And my companion Contact form process, available for free at the site, also uses several techniques to block bots on Contact forms. And my other plugin that adds additional protection to Contact Form 7 forms. Plus the new version (pending; to be released later this month) uses additional techniques to foil the automated process. So your comments are valid, and my plugins are aware - and block - those techniques.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

The most common misconception is, that modern spammers use comment forms. They don't care about them, at all. They post comment's data directly, bypassing form's processing, with its validation, captcha, etc, leaving comment forms to legitimate users (humans). In a process of detection comments spam, two players take part - WordPress, and a supplementing plugin. With correct settings, WordPress is pretty successful in catching spam, but cannot catch them all. The plugin should further refine the process.

## Solution

The following method, implemented on my various production websites, for years, made them virtually spam-free. You might be skeptical, so don't take my word for it, just try it, and make your own judgement.

#### Part 1. WordPress

In `Settings -> Discussion` set these suggested options:

Check ***Allow people to post comments on new articles*** box

Check ***Comment author must fill out name and email*** box

Check ***Comment must be manually approved*** box

Set the value of ***Hold a comment in the queue if it contains*** to 1

Play with other options according to your needs.

#### Part 2. Must use plugin

Make a file `fpw-antispam.php`, with code below, and place it in `/wp-content/mu-plugins` folder.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: FPW Anti Spam

Description: Handles spammed comments and disables comments trash

Plugin URI: http://fw2s.com/
Version: 0.1
Author: Frank P. Walentynowicz
Author URI: http://fw2s.com/

Copyright 2014 Frank P. Walentynowicz (email : frankpw@fw2s.com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
published by the Free Software Foundation.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

// prevent direct access
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))  
    die('Direct access to this script is not allowed!');

function fpwDeleteComment($commentID, $approved, $commentData) {
    if('trash' === $approved || 'spam' === $approved) {
        $requestedBy = (empty($commentData['comment_author_url'])) ? 'WordPress' : 'must use plugin';
        if(wp_delete_comment($commentID, true)) {
            error_log("Comment ({$commentID}) has been PERMANENTLY DELETED by {$requestedBy}");
        } else {
            error_log("Comment ({$commentID}) - delete failed");
        }
    } else {
        error_log("Comment ({$commentID}) - status: {$approved}");
    }   
}
add_action('comment_post', 'fpwDeleteComment', 100, 3);

function fpwDeleteTrashedComment($commentID, $commentObject) {
    if(wp_delete_comment($commentID, true)) {
        error_log("Comment ({$commentID}) has been TRASHED and PERMANENTLY DELETED");
    } else {
        error_log("Comment ({$commentID}) - delete failed");
    }
}
add_action('comment_trash_', 'fpwDeleteTrashedComment', 100, 2);

function fpwCommentHandler($approved , $commentdata) {
    return empty($commentdata['comment_author_url']) ? $approved : 'trash';
}
add_filter('pre_comment_approved' , 'fpwCommentHandler' , 100, 2);
```

**Note:** `error_log` function calls help you to trace, unobtrusively, the progress of the plugin. Once you become confident that it works as expected, you can comment out these calls.

#### Part 3. CSS

Add the following line to `style.css` of your current theme:

```
p.comment-form-url { display: none }
```

This will hide author's URL field from human users, only, so they cannot, accidentally, fill out this field. Remember to leave comment's template intact - do not remove this field!

## UPDATE

Because it worked so well, I didn't even look back to do any changes to the method above. After posting my answer, I've decided to see, if any improvement is possible. The final result follows.

Must use plugin is reduced to one filter only, and most important change is, that spammed comments are dropped, without any access to the database.

```
function fpwCommentHandler($approved , $commentdata) {
    if (!empty($commentdata['comment_author_url']) || 'spam' == $approved || 'trash' == $approved)
        return new WP_Error( 'spam', 'Comment spam detected!');
    return $approved;
}
add_filter('pre_comment_approved' , 'fpwCommentHandler' , 100, 2);
```

**Note:** if you don't feel comfortable, to use it as is (without logging), you can add logging, on your own. I've implemented this new method on my production websites, already.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by editing the max url string length in comment.php from 200 to 1. Only problem is any wordpress update will overwrite this each time. How would I go about making this change in functions instead?

Comment: Turns out there's a wp_get_comment_fields_max_lengths filter at line 1187 of https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/comment.php. So looks like you might be able to filter $lengths['comment_author_url'] to 1. Not 100% sure it's called at the right time, but wouldn't be hard to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that limiting URLs will block all spam, nope. Most spam is automated: the spammer finds your comment form, creates an automated form-filler, then fills in the comment with their spam.

So xpam problems will not go away if you ban URLs from comments.

I know a lot about preventing spam in contact forms and comments; wrote a plugin and standalone code to prevent form spam (see `[here][1]` ). My techniques are mostly successful, but still get some spam. Got a new version in the works that will reduce automated spam even more.

You might think about enabling reCAPTCHA on your comment forms. That helps reduce spam, but nothing that I've found (and I've looked for many years) will completely remove spam.

Hidden fields don't work. "Questions" like "what is 2 + 4" don't work. Captchas don't work (although the version 2 ReCaptcha is more effective).

My practice is to enable Akismet, and use my "[FormSpammerTrap for Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formspammertrap-for-comments/)" plugin (which has some additional techniques to reduce the chance that a spam-bot will fill out my comment).

That helps get rid of a lot of comments. But nothing is 100% effective - not even my solutions.

Comment: Modern spammers don't care about comment forms at all. They post comment's data directly, bypassing form's processing, with its validation, captchas, etc. Read my answer for details.